# Jenkins configuration issue

Tags: jenkins

I am facing error while adding JDK 1.8.0_60.

> A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug
>   tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it
>   is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us
>   gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue,
>   please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the
>   entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant
>   plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has
>   happened.

Stack trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON:init
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:918)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:2917)`jdk1.8.0_60`
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor235.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of init
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:919)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:916)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: Are you running on Linux or Windows? And is the jdk installed on that machine (server)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the plugins wherever you see warnings on Manage Jenkins page of Jenkins. Follow the following steps:

1. Go to Jenkins Ex: http://localhost:8080/
2. Click on Manage Jenkins
3. You will see some warnings.
   **Ex:**
   Warnings have been published for the following currently installed components:
   Jenkins 2.289.1 core and libraries
   Multiple security vulnerabilities in Jenkins 2.299 and earlier, LTS 2.289.1 and earlier
   **Note:** You may get different warnings (one or more warnings)
4. Right click on each and every warnings (Please do it one by one if you have more than one warnings)
5. Now go to Manage Plugins (on the same page.. or Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins)
6. Click on Installed tab
7. Paste the copied link in the Search box
8. Uninstall the Plugin
9. Restart the Jenkins once you uninstall all the unwanted or unsecured plugins

Please repeat the above steps until you uninstall all the unwanted plugins that showed up as warnings on Manage Jenkins page.

Once you uninstall,  you will not get any Logging ID error message while configuring. Juts make sure that you don't see any warnings.

Hope this helps! Please like it if it has worked or unlike if it didn't help you.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. StackExchange is not about *like* and chit chat - [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if interested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using chrome? Try firefox or IE first, this issue happened in some specified version of chrome browser.

Also, this bug has been reported on the jenkins official bug tracker and marked as **blocker**, keep an eye on this.
[Exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON:init (on WIndows 7)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31497)
[Error while running parametrized build: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29988)

Comment: I have tried configuring in Firefox as well.Still getting an error,I think it's genetic and not browser specific

Comment: same here tried edge and still not working